# Writing cursor to delete objects greater or less than particular FID

Tags: arcpy, cursor, feature-class, update, delete

I have a couple of shapefile attribute tables I want to delete items greater than 10 FID using a cursor. My user arguments are the file path, FID, and the number that is the minimum number not to delete. A user argument would be: **C:/example.shp FID 10**

```
import arcpy, os, sys

# copy script to backup so that I don't accidentally mess up my original file

inputFeatClass = sys.argv[1]
fcCopy = 'C:/pratice/' + os.path.basename(inputFC)
arcpy.Copy_management(inputFeatClass, fcCopy)
numMin = sys.argv[2]
x = sys.argv[3]

try:
    cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fcCopy,[numMin])
    # delete rows who's x value is greater than numMin
    for row in cursor:
        if numMin < x:
            cursor.deleteRow()
            print ('Remove row: {0}'.format(row[0]))
    del cursor
except:
    print 'fix it'
    del cursor
```

When i run this, it returns nothing in the IDE but also 'Returned exit code 0' on the bottom. I figure it's something in my try statement that needs fixing, but how do I fix the statement- which I am guessing may be the comparison statement using < if I had to guess, **because when I alter it to x < numMin, it deletes all the rows.**

Comment: I think you should remove your try/except statements while testing because they can mask error messages which might be very helpful to you.

Comment: Personally. I wouldn't use a cursor to do this.  Instead I'd use `arcpy.Select_analysis()` tool.

Comment: `FID` is a ***really*** dangerous thing to delete on, because if you delete FID==1, the previous FID=2 becomes FID=1.  A far safer way to delete rows is to use `DeleteRows_management`, which operates on the selected set.  And safer still is to Select the rows you want to keep, and use `FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion` to write to a new dataset.

Comment: Your `numMin` and `x` arguments are also currently strings, not integers.  Meaning `('15' < '2') == True`

Comment: You could pass a `where` clause (as 3rd parameter) to the UpdateCursor, e.g. `'FID>10'` and get rid of the `if numMin < x` check. See [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm)

Comment: What you are actually checking now is `'FID' < 10`, meaning, the text 'FID' is smaller than 10. This doesn't make sense. You probably need `row[0] > x`. And also take note of the comment by @mikewatt

Comment: Thanks everyone! All your advice truly helped, I started by casting items to integers and then using Berend's advice by using row[0] instead of 'FID'

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is the `if numMin < x:` should be `if row[0] > x`.
`if numMin < x` is the same as `if 'FID' < 10`

Also it's better practice to use `with` statement when using arcpy cursors.

```py
import arcpy
import os

# copy script to backup so that I don't accidentally mess up my original file
inputFeatClass = sys.argv[1]
fcCopy = 'C:/pratice/' + os.path.basename(inputFC)
arcpy.Copy_management(inputFeatClass, fcCopy)
numMin = sys.argv[2]
x = sys.argv[3]

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fcCopy, numMin) as cur:
    for row in cur:
        if row[0] > x:
            cursor.deleteRow()
            print ('Remove row: {}'.format(row[0]))
```

If the request is always on the `FID` field, you could remove it for your argument and use :
`with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fcCopy, 'OID@') as cur:`
https://desktop.arcgis.com/fr/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm